# Extracting tag names, attributes, values and text context from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I want to extract all element tag names, attributes, values and text content from a given xml string.

eg:

```html
<instructor >
 <title degree= “PhD” year = “2012” school = “USC”>Professor</title>
 <name> 
  <first>FirstName</first>
  <last>LastName</last>
 </name>
 <course level = “Junior”>XML</course>
 <officeHours>10</officeHours>
</instructor>
```

I want my code to return all tag names, attributes, values and text content.
eg: Tag Name: instructor,title,name,course, officeHours.
attibutes: degree, year, school,level.
values:phd,2012,USC.
text: professor,firstName,LastName,10.

How to do this in C#.

Comment: What is the destination of the extraction? Values concatenated into a string or some data structure?

Comment: In a HashMap<String, ArrayList>.

Comment: And what are key and ArrayList in this context? Like in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given *root* XElement, obtained from something like:

```
var root = XElement.Parse(myXmlString);
```

And pre-initialized `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` (equivalent of HashMap), the following function will do what you require:

```
static void TraverseXElement(XElement elem, Dictionary<string, List<string>> aggregation)
{
    const string valuesKey = "Values";
    const string tagNameKey = "Tag Name";
    const string attributesKey = "Attributes";

    aggregation[tagNameKey].Add(elem.Name.LocalName);
    foreach (var childText in elem.Nodes().OfType<XText>())
    {
        //immediate values, even in case of wrongly formed XML
        aggregation[valuesKey].Add(childText.Value); 
    }

    foreach (var element in elem.Elements())
    {
        TraverseXElement(element, aggregation);
    }

    foreach (var attr in elem.Attributes())
    {
        aggregation[attributesKey].Add(attr.Name.LocalName);
        aggregation[valuesKey].Add(attr.Value);
    }
}
```

Reordering the last two loops will change the order of values.